# Winsound crashes Tkinter GUI

Tags: windows-7, crash, tkinter, python-3.3

I have a program that uses a TKinter GUI. I'm trying to display a GUI box at the same time as using winsound to play a sound. It works but after the box freezes and it crashes. There are no error reports. I'm programming with Python 3.3 on a Windows 7 machine! PLEASE HELP! Here is the code for the box and sound:

```
          t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2))
          t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox, args = ("The sky is up.",))
          t2.start()

          t1.start()
```

Comment: So I also made a smaller program containing just that portion of my bigger program, and the smaller program works flawlessly! What's wrong with my bigger program?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the loop I have in the bigger program. I really need help with this!

Comment: I suggest you add the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your GUI code in a thread, that's likely the problem. Tkinter was designed to run in a single thread, preferably the main thread. If you access any tkinter code or interact with any widget in more than a single thread, it will crash.  The fact that you are putting `lipgui.msgbox` in a thread makes me think that's what's happening.

Comment: If that is the case. Is there any other way (besides threading) I could run the Gui and the sound file at the same time?

Comment: As long as you play the sound file in a thread and keep all gui functions in the main thread you should be ok

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

I think I might know what you are talking about....try adding something like this just before the line of code that you think makes the program freeze...

```
root.update()
```

"root" is the name of your master tkinter window!
I have never worked with the sound module that you speak of, but I think should do the trick!

Comment: Well the problem is the GUI is a module that I programmed using tkinter. I tried this and it didn't work!